# Using many lines in a foreach node

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I intended to make a TikZ graph with a single `\foreach` that drew points in a chart and labeled them on the side. My `\foreach` drew all the labels on top of each other. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Was PGFplots a better idea for this task?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3);
\foreach \x/\y/\col/\char in {
1/1/black/A,
2/2/red/B
}
{
\fill[color=\col] (\x,\y) circle [radius=0.1];
\node[align=left] at (3,3) {
\tikz\fill[color=\col] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1]; \char \\
};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Odd output]

I'd like to have a 'side panel' that explains what each color means, but I didn't find a clean input.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3);
\foreach \x/\y/\col in {
1/1/black/A,
2/2/red/B
}
{
\fill[color=\col] (\x,\y) circle [radius= 0.1];
}
\node[align=left] at (3,3) {
\tikz\fill[color=black] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1]; A \\
\tikz\fill[color=red] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1]; B \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're drawing all the nodes at `(3,3)`, so they're all drawn on top of each other (you can also see this with the circle at `(3,3)` itself).

---

### pgfplots Solution

A bit overkill, but since the regular `TikZ` solution is already covered, I'll add it anyway.

`pgfplots` can make use of meta information for each data point when doing scatter plots. We use this meta information to assign each data point to a class, and each class gets its own style.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0.5,
            xmax=2.5,
            legend pos=outer north east,
        ]

        \addplot[
            only marks,
            scatter,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            scatter/classes={
                A={mark=triangle*,blue},%
                B={mark=square*,red}},
        ]
            table[x=x,y=y,meta=char] {%
            x y char 
            1 1 A
            2 2 B
        };
        \legend{A,B};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:[image: pgfplots result]

See the `pgfplots` manual on page 254f. for legend positioning, pages 181 and following for different `mark` styles and pages 112 and following for some information about `scatter/classes`.

---

### Old Solution

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the question originally, but leaving this here for posterity.

Is this your desired result (or something similar)?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->] (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3);
    \foreach \x/\y/\col/\char in {
        1/1/black/A,
        2/2/red/B,
        3/3/red/C
    }
    {
        \fill[color=\col] (\x,\y) circle [radius=0.1];
        \node[xshift=1em] at (\x,\y) {\char};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I hope I have understood your intentions correctly. If not, let me know. You could use `pgfplots` for this, yes, but it's not a strict necessity.

Comment: I've edited my solution to make it more clear.

Comment: Aha, so basically what you're after is a legend, I think. Sorry for my misinterpretation.
I'm trying to figure out if I can get this done nicely with `pgfplots` at the moment. I'll add it to my answer if I find something which works nicely, but for a pure `TikZ` solution I think AboAmmar has got you covered now. :-)

Comment: His answer does work and it's automatic but remains a bit hacky since the `yshift` has to be specified. Do you know of a better way?

Comment: You're probably not going to get around it unless you simply put it into a second `node` (in which case you're going to have to specify a second node instead of `yshift`, it's up to you which you prefer).
I have added a `pgfplots` solution. I have made it look slightly different to show you what can be done and given you some pages from the manual in case you want to customize it further.

Comment: Yikes! PGFplots is quite impressive.

Answer (score 2):

No real need for PGFplots for such a simple case.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (3,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,3);

\foreach \x/\y/\col/\char in {1/1/black/A, 2/2/red/B} {
  \fill[color=\col] (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];
  \fill[color=\col,yshift=-\x em] (3,3)node[right]{\footnotesize\char} circle [radius=2pt];
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlg]